# Please help extract text from HTML tags using Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have the following HTML text :

```
Country/<i>List it here</i><br><font color="#ff00ff">Dubai</font><br><br>
```

How do I extract 'Dubai' out of the above HTML?  I have few hundreds such lines, kind of urgent, so not researching BeautifulSoup or XML parser implementation.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want something quick and dirty, you could use:

```
re.match(r'.*>([^<>]*)</font>.*', s).group(1)
```

This just grabs all of the non angle-brackety things before a closing font tag. Again, not suitable for "real" parsing.